# One-sided rounded buttons in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, button, expression-blend

I want to make a collection of buttons in silverlight.
They are in a collection that goes from left to right and the buttons are lined up so that they are touching on the left and right sides.
Here is the rub:
The collection has rounded corners but the buttons in between the end buttons in the collection do not have rounded ends.  So basically, for the buttons on the far left and right side of the collection, they have to be somewhat special because they have to have one flat vertical side and one rounded side.  Is this possible to do in silverlight without resorting to making a special bitmap for the end buttons?

One idea I have is somehow declare a canvas with a bitmap background and then have overlapping ellipse and rectangle

```
        <Canvas Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,381,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Background="Black">
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Stroke="Black" Width="58" Height="61" Canvas.Left="7" Canvas.Top="16" />
            <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Stroke="White" Width="65" StrokeThickness="0" Height="59" Canvas.Left="31" Canvas.Top="17" />
        </Canvas>
```

Comment: Are you data binding for your list of buttons? If not then this is very easy to do simply by having left, middle, and right button templates. If you're databinding then you want to have your button models have a property for the style of the different types of templates.

Comment: You know you can get round-corners simply by editing the button template's internal border, right?

Comment: @xanadont, but that is for both sides, right?  RadiusX and RadiusY just tell how much of a curve the ends have.  But it is for both ends of the Rectangle

Comment: You need to first learn how to edit and apply a custom template (plenty of resources online, big topic). Once you know that you can set each, individual corner radius in a border: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.cornerradius(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of the effect you are trying to achieve that utilizes custom `ControlTemplate` to skin the buttons in three ways:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonLeftStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="DarkGray" CornerRadius="10,0,0,10">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonCenterStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="DarkGray" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonRightStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="DarkGray" CornerRadius="0,10,10,0">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Width="75" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource ButtonLeftStyle}" Content="Left"/>
        <Rectangle Width="2"/>
        <Button Width="75" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource ButtonCenterStyle}" Content="Center"/>
        <Rectangle Width="2"/>
        <Button Width="75" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRightStyle}" Content="Right"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And this looks like:

[image: Rounded Buttons]

There's a lot more you can do here but this shows an approach you can use.  Here's a great blog article with more information and examples of this technique:

- [Silverlight Tutorial Part 7: Using Control Templates to Customize a Control's Look and Feel](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-7-using-control-templates-to-customize-a-control-s-look-and-feel.aspx)

Comment: This nukes all the baked-in control template behavior. I'd suggest copying the built-in template first and then cherry-pick the custom edits as needed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: @xanadont: Yes, in order to keep the demonstration small, I've left out some things.  For example, the chrome is useless since it is square.  Also with the visual state manager you can handle mouse over and focus, etc.  My answer mainly focuses on the shape construction question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a visual trick.  First of all, my trick required I placed the buttons on an image that would represent the background.  The buttons were somewhat transparent so the color of this background came through

The buttons in the middle be simple rectangle canvas classes.  While the end buttons had rounded ends.

The middle buttons were in front of the buttons on the end and they overlapped them.

The buttons were transparent and so normally it would not work because you would be able to see the end buttons edges behind the middle buttons.  I solved this by putting a rectangle filled with the color of the background image "between" (think in 3D layered depth terms) the end buttons and the rectangle shapped buttons in front of it.  The colored rectangles only were positioned in front of the end buttons that were behind the rectangle buttons in front of them.

This was kind of a hack but it worked.  When I have time, I will try the solutions suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, even simpler, based on Rick'S, as you just want to use the styles to address the rounded corners of your button template border:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
  <Grid.Resources>
   <!-- Default Template -->
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
         <Border x:Name="Border" Background="DarkGray" CornerRadius="0">
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
         </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <!-- Custom Styles for edges -->
    <Style x:Key="ButtonLeftStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10,0,0,10" TargetName="Border"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonRightStyle" TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,10,10,0" TargetName="Border"/>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Width="75" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource ButtonLeftStyle}" Content="Left"/>
    <Rectangle Width="2"/>
    <Button Width="75" Height="25" Content="Center"/>
    <Rectangle Width="2"/>
    <Button Width="75" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRightStyle}" Content="Right"/>
</StackPanel>
```